# GroupBy Laravel MySql Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Ive tried many variations of this however mysql is not my strongest suit. Here is the query I have and am trying to run:

```
$vendors = $this->account->vendors()
            ->whereRaw('version_id = (SELECT MAX(version_id) from vendors)')
            ->groupBy('vendor_code')
            ->orderBy($this->orderBy, $this->sortBy)
            ->paginate($this->display_per_page);
```

What i'm trying to accomplish is to get the higest version_id from each vendor_code group. But no matter how I structure this query I keep getting the error. If you can point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Here is the error i'm getting:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'eventer.vendors.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from `vendors` where `vendors`.`account_id` = 106 and `vendors`.`account_id` is not null and version_id = (SELECT MAX(version_id) from vendors) and `vendors`.`deleted_at` is null group by `vendor_code` order by `name` asc limit 10 offset 0)

Below is my table structure:

```
id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  account_id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  vendor_code int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  version_id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  name varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  street varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  city varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  province varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  postal_code varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  phone varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  email varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  website varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  industry varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  created_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  deleted_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

Comment: "I keep getting the error".. what error?

Comment: This - `version_id = (SELECT MAX(version_id) from vendors)` isn't going to work as I think you expect. It'll find the single maximum `version_id`, and return only vendors with specifically that version.

Comment: any idea of how I can find the max version_id and group by vendor_code?

Answer (score 0):

Select column name which is in group by

```
    ->select("table_name.vendor_code","other_column")
```

Also to avoid ambiguous column use table name or alias before column name

Comment: Still gives me an error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'eventer.vendors.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `vendors`.`vendor_code` from `vendors` where `vendors`.`account_id` = 106 and `vendors`.`account_id` is not null and version_id = (SELECT MAX(version_id) from vendors) and `vendors`.`deleted_at` is null group by `vendors`.`vendor_code` order by `name` asc limit 10

Comment: Congrats you fixed first now same for second , select those columns also which is in `orderBy`

Comment: Thanks for the tip :D. Is there any way to select all columns in the table instead of listing all of them?

Comment: Or just try without `orderBy` if get success then add column name in `select` and use `orderBy`

Comment: You can use `table_name.*` or `alias.*` to get all column

Comment: Here is what I have now: $vendors = $this->account->vendors()
            ->select("vendors.*")
            ->whereRaw('version_id = (SELECT MAX(version_id) from vendors)')
//            ->addSelect('select vendor_code from vendors where version_id = (select max(version_id) from vendors) group by vendor_code')
            ->groupBy('vendors.vendor_code')
//            ->orderBy($this->orderBy, $this->sortBy)
            ->paginate($this->display_per_page);

Comment: still gives me an error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'eventer.vendors.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `vendors`.* from `vendors` where `vendors`.`account_id` = 106 and `vendors`.`account_id` is not null and version_id = (SELECT MAX(version_id) from vendors) and `vendors`.`deleted_at` is null group by `vendors`.`vendor_code` limit 10 offset 0)

Comment: Share your table structures in your question?

Comment: Please see the updated question with the table structure